# Detect if Ajax request has been sent

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I just cannot figure out how to check in PHP if an ajax request has been sent (form submission).

neither

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest')
```

nor

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
```

gets executed.

Here is the javascript code.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'login.php',
       data: $(this).serialize()
   });
```

"this" is referring to the form. I have checked it and it is in the correct format username=dean&password=123123

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add an error callback. Does it get triggered?

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` is not guaranteed to be present. Are you sure it's even being sent?

Comment: the error callback is not triggered. Instead the success callback is triggered. The problem is with the php, it does not detect the header. Is there maybe a better way of checking that an ajax request has been sent?

Comment: Are you sure that line of php is even being reached?

Comment: Yes I am, i test the else statement too, and it does reach the line, it just does not recognize any ajax requests.

Comment: very easy to tell in browser console...look at network tab

Comment: @charlietfl I think he is trying to log people in via AJAX by passing credentials to login.php in a querystring and is trying to determine if they were sent from an AJAX for security reasons. I think.

Answer (score 0):

Add a callback...

```
  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'login.php',
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success : function(response){
             console.log(response);
        }
   });
```

Comment: The ajax is executed without any problems. Adding callback does not make PHP detect it. I need a way of making PHP code trigger when I send the ajax request.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "making PHP code trigger"? Are you trying to log a user in by passing credentials to login.php?

Comment: Yes, I am validating the input using javascript (username and password filled out) and then post the data to the same page login.php through ajax.

Comment: Are you trying to determine if its an AJAX request because of security concerns?

Comment: @DaveCameron  `this` is likely not what you think it is. Define it outsise of `$.ajax`. Browser console will inspect request and tell you exactly what  is sent/received, and status

Comment: When I do this sort of thing I set up a web service and I'll pass the credentials in a JSON string `'{ "username" : "' + u + '", "password" : "' + p + '" }'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use browser developer tool (FireBug Network panel if you're using Mozilla Firefox), to make sure that the appropriate header is sent. And which version of jQuery are you using?
Also, if you are using PHP-FPM as backend for Nginx http server, Nginx may not send some HTTP-headers to backend, depending on it's configuration.